# Can "so" express a reason not a result?

Tags: meaning, so

> Going through customs to leave a country can sometimes be very
>   frustrating. First she was asked why she was not rolling her carryon.
>   The handle got stuck when she got off the car **so** she had been
>   forced to open the suitcase to maneuver the handle back to the
>   suitcase.

Can **so** express **a reason** and used as **"because".** In this passage first she had been forced  to open the suit case (past perfect) and then the handle got stuck (past simple). The handle got stuck because or after she had been forced to open suitcase.

I really thought and still think that **so**  express(ed) always a result!

> My car is broken **so** I am going to the garage

Answer (score 5):

No, **so** is not interchangeable with **because** in those sentences.

Their meanings are related and they both serve to mark a **reason** but let's look at your example.

> My car is broken **so** I am going to the garage
>  I am going to the
>   garage **because** my car is broken

Both sentences express exactly the same meaning but notice where is the **reason** located in each one.

> REASON **so** ACTION
>  ACTION **because** REASON

In the quoted text, **first** the handle got stuck and that's the reason why **later** she was forced to open the suitcase.

> She was forced to open the suitcase **because** previously the handle
>   got stuck
>  The handle got stock previously **so** she was force to
>   open the suitcase

[previously = when she got off the car]

Additional information about the use of **so** [in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/so).

WARNING: I don't mean that you can ALWAYS, IN EVERY CASE, swap the order of the clauses and replace "so" by "because". I was just using the examples provided in the original question, simplifying them in an effort to explain the use of those conjuctions. Please check the provided link, there are cases like the one exposed by @Astralbee where you CAN NOT reorder the clauses in such way.

I've been pointed by @Astralbee that my reasoning is wrong but the Cambridge Dictionary entries related to **so** and **therefore** seems to back me up

[**so**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so)

> and for **that** reason; therefore:

**[therefore](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/therefore)**

> because of that; for **that** reason

Please, notice the presence of the determiner **that**, it refers to something that has been PREVIOUSLY mentioned. USUALLY when you use **so**, the reason, the cause, has appeared before. The quoted text of the OP fullfils this structure.

> got stuck BEFORE had been opened

But let's check what **because** means

**[because](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/because)**

> for the reason **that**

According to the dictionary, USUALLY the reason is explained AFTER **because**. All depends on where **that** is located in these definitions.

Comment: In that case why past perfect is used for had been forced, i see no reel reason if it happened after

Comment: all the sentence must be in past perfect because it is used as a flashback

Comment: @user5577 I've just written examples to answer this specific question about "so vs. because". I think that you have another question with the same text in relation with the use of past perfect.

Comment: yes but I ve deleted this question because i thought had been forced was the first action as past perfect was used but now I am completly lost why past perfect was used if it came after

Comment: But past perfect does not point always the first action, you got to see the whole context. I think that in your context, you can use "was forced" to express exactly the same that "had been forced". Maybe you should ask again simplifying a bit "was forced vs had been forced"

Comment: But you could say "I am going to the garage *so* I can get my car repaired". That uses "so" and has action before reason.

Comment: @Astralbee Good point. I've added a related link about the use of "so". As stated in the Cambridge Dictionary, you're right, so can be used (1) introducing clauses of result or decision and (2) introducing clauses of reason or explanation. In example I think that replacing "so" by "because" is not completely idiomatic, isn't it?

Comment: i don't know if it is idiomatic but for me it will work as a reason to justify past perfect

Comment: @user5577 Let me insists, it seems that your main concern is the past perfect and not the use of so or because. You should ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @user5577 I have to say, I think this answer is incorrect. All the examples are right, but the reasoning is wrong. It is not always possible to substitute so/because by swapping around the clauses. I think this may be why you are getting hung up on the tense - if the cause of something has happened in the past you can't flip it around and make it a future reason.

Comment: which answer?  the one from RubioRic or yours  But in all example you gave the clause before the conjunction so came first      I am going to the garage (first) so I can get my car repaired. I have to renew my passport first) so I can go abroad next year.

Comment: @Astralbee I didn't mean that such swapping is always correct. And OP's confussion is centered in the use of the past perfect. The so/because problem is just tangential.

Answer (score 5):

The words "so" and "because" are **not** interchangeable as they have different meaning and usage. Both are used as a *conjunction* to join clauses which could include an action and related statement, but it depends on whether you are stating a *reason* or a *cause*.

"Because" is used when you are specifying a *cause* for something. There is even a clue in the word - "*be-cause*". "So" is a little different because it literally means "therefore". It joins two clauses that follow on from one another logically and that *could* include a reason for the action, for example:

> I am going to the garage *so* I can get my car repaired.

Getting your car repaired is the *reason* you are going to the garage, but it is not the *cause*. The cause is that your car is broken. One logically follows from the other.

A cause would usually be something that has happened in the past or is inevitable, for example:

> I went to the hospital because I broke my leg. (past cause)
>
> I have to renew my passport because it expires next month. (future cause)

But a *reason* is more your motivation for doing something rather than something inevitable.

> I have to renew my passport so I can go abroad next year.

So in answer to your question "*can "so" express a reason not a result?*", "so" *always* expresses a reason, but not a *cause*. In your example of the suitcase handle getting stuck it sounds like the action of having to open the case to adjust the handle was a *result* of the handle previously getting stuck, so the former statement is logically the *cause* of the latter, and "so" is appropriate. It is coincidental that in this particular sentence you could replace the word with "because" and it remains grammatical, however the meaning would be completely changed and it would read that the latter statement was the cause of the former.

Comment: Notice that it's a bit difficult to follow your explanation knowing the definition of reason. reason = the CAUSE of an event https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reason You're trying to establish a subjective distinction between them

Comment: @RubioRic Well you're misquoting slightly. It is "a cause, explanation, or justification for an action or event". If you then go on to look up the individual definitions of "cause" and "justification" you'll find they are quite different. Look - questions here get closed if they can be looked up in a dictionary. That is the minimum research we expect people to do before asking a question. I feel you are just having a go at my answer because yours is patently incorrect, flies in the face of dictionary definitions and suggests a non-existent rule about the ordering of "reasons" and "actions".

Comment: I think that the one "having a go at my answer" is you. I believe that you are the only one that have downvoted it. It seems that my answer is not so "patently" wrong for the community. I edited my answer after your comment to specify clearly that I wasn't defining a rule, I explicitly indicated that I was referencing the examples, that it can not be applied for every case. And whatever you write, it's difficult to differentiate between the concepts of reason and cause as I've pointed with references.

Comment: @RubioRic Yes I did downvote it *after* I left a comment advising you it was wrong and you *still* didn't fix it. Your answer is wrong and could mislead people on this site for years to come. If you can point me to any reference that shows your imaginary "REASON so ACTION / ACTION because REASON" rule then I will reverse my vote and eat my words.

Comment: I can't fix it. If I remove that I'll have to remove the entire post. What I don't understand is if my answer is so wrong why I got more upvotes than you? I need at least another reputed opinion backing yours to remove my answer.

Comment: I've tried to improve my answer once again. Reading the Cambridge Dictionary, I think that you're mixing two different meanings of so: (1) therefore and (2) used before you give an explanation for the action that you have just mentioned. But I was always talking about (1)